# Iterate through variable number of arguments in function without passing nil

Tags: objective-c, c

I, like many, constantly have to look up date codes for date formatter.  I decided to make a file that will make it easier for me to remember them all.  I include a function for readability that I declare like this:

```
NSString * dateFormatString(NSString * string1, ...) {

    // Parse out Args
    va_list args;
    va_start(args,string1);

    // Set up our Format String
    NSMutableString * formatString = [NSMutableString string];

    // Build Format string
    for (NSString * arg = string1; arg != nil; arg = va_arg(args, NSString*)) {
        [formatString appendString:arg];
    }

    va_end(args);

    return formatString;
}
```

So, I can then program my `NSDateFormatter` like this:

```
dateFormatter.dateFormatString = dateFormatString(DKDayOfWeekFull, @", ", DKMonthNameFull, @" ", DKDayOfMonthComplete, nil);
```

You could do achieve pretty much the same thing by declaring:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@ %@", DKDayOfWeekFull, DKMonthNameFull, DKDayOfMonthComplete];
```

However, if you're describing a date with more variables like "Sat, Jan 14 2006 at 7:52 AM" it would have to be:

```
 NSString * dateFormatterString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@ %@ %@ 'at' %@:%@ %@", DKDayOfWeekAbbreviated, DKMonthNameAbbreviated, DKDayOfMonthComplete, DKYearComplete, DKHour12hrComplete, DKMinutes2Digits, DKAmPm];
```

Which I personally think is a bit more readable like this:

```
NSString * dateFormatterString = dateFormatString(DKDayOfWeekAbbreviated, @", ", DKMonthNameAbbreviated, @" ", DKDayOfMonthComplete, @" ", DKYearComplete, @"'at' ", DKHour12hrComplete, @":", DKMinutes2Digits, @" ", DKAmPm, nil);
```

#### Question

I would prefer a way to iterate through the variables without having to pass nil into the function.  Is there another way to iterate through a variable argument list, other than:

```
for (NSString * arg = string1; arg != nil; arg = va_arg(args, NSString*)) {
    [formatString appendString:arg];
}
```

Comment: The compiler will warn you of a forgotten `nil` if you declare your function like this: `NSString *dateFormatString(NSString *, ...) NS_REQUIRES_NIL_TERMINATION;`

Comment: @RobMayoff - That's perfect! It fills it right in so people won't forget.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I assume you meant to say `dateFormatter.dateFormat = ...`, since `NSDateFormatter` has no `dateFormatString` property.

I assume `DKDayOfWeekAbbreviated` is a string constant defined as `@"E"`, and `DKDayOfWeekFull` is `@"EEEE"`, and so on, based on [UTS #35](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

If that is so, here's a different approach.  Define your constants like this:

```
#define DKDayOfWeekAbbreviated @"E"
#define DKDayOfWeekFull @"EEEE"
#define DKMonthNameFull @"MMMM"
#define DKDayOfMonthComplete @"dd"
```

Then use compile-time string concatenation to build your strings.  The compiler merges two adjacent string constants. For example, `"hello " "world"` becomes `"hello world"`, and `@"hello " @"world"` becomes `@"hello world"`.  In fact, you can omit the second and later `@` characters, so `@"hello " "world"` becomes `@"hello world"`.

Thus:

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = DKDayOfWeekFull ", " DKMonthNameFull " " DKDayOfMonthComplete;
```

You don't need a helper function or varargs.

Comment: Slick. I always forget that you can append string constants this way.

Comment: This is very cool! I didn't know you could do that. Definitely worth an upvote!  I have two problems that this causes.  1. I don't get autofill past the first variable. 2. I currently have descriptions declared in my keys using `/*! description */` so I can see what each key does while searching.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to support variable arguments using the standard C syntax is to do what you are doing.

But you have another option - use an `NSArray`.

Your function becomes:

```
NSString * dateFormatString(NSArray *strings) {
    // Set up our Format String
    NSMutableString * formatString = [NSMutableString string];

    // Build Format string
    for (NSString * arg in strings) {
        [formatString appendString:arg];
    }

    return formatString;
}
```

or simply do:

```
NSString * dateFormatString(NSArray *strings) {
    return [strings componentsJoinedByString:@""];
}
```

And you call it like this:

```
dateFormatter.dateFormatString = dateFormatString(@[ DKDayOfWeekFull, @", ", DKMonthNameFull, @" ", DKDayOfMonthComplete ]);
```

No need for `nil` using the modern `NSArray` syntax.

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy, do you know how NSString & NSLog get away with it?

Comment: Good question because lots of other methods do need the `nil` terminator.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that they parse the format string and count instances of `%` to know how many args to iterate.

Comment: It's a little more complicated than just counting `%` chars, but yes the format string indicates how many arguments follow, hence no need for a nil at the end.  Examples: `%*.*s` consumes three args. `%%` consumes no args.

Comment: More succinctly: `[strings componentsJoinedByString:@""]`